# jQuery full calendar: set a different color to each event from front-end

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, fullcalendar

This is how I'm using the plugin:

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
    jQuery('#booking-calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        events: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/bookings-feed.php'
    });

    jQuery( '#apartment-selector' ).change( function() {
        apartment = jQuery( this ).val()
        jQuery('#booking-calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents' )
        jQuery('#booking-calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource',  {
            url: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/bookings-feed.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                apartment : apartment
            }
        })
    })
})
```

And this is how it looks:

[image]

As you can see it's a bit difficult to track when an event starts and ends, so I was thinking of changing the color of each event.

The problem here is that each event might be split in different weeks (like in the example) and each week has a different DOM event (which makes sense) and they don't have any related class,

How can I color each event differently?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

To colorize each event differently there are a couple approaches you can take to tackle your problem.

1. Update the event feed '/bookings-feed.php' and add color(background and border), backgroundColor, textColor, or borderColor to the event object http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/.

   ```
    events: [{
        title  : 'event1',
        start  : '2010-01-01',
        color  : '#000'
    }]
   ```
2. Separate and update the event feeds to use eventSources. Which allows you to group events by color and text color. http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_array/.

```js
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventSources: [
        // your event source
        {
            events: [ // put the array in the `events` property
                {
                    title  : 'event1',
                    start  : '2010-01-01'
                },
                {
                    title  : 'event2',
                    start  : '2010-01-05',
                    end    : '2010-01-07'
                },
                {
                    title  : 'event3',
                    start  : '2010-01-09 12:30:00',
                }
            ],
            color: 'black',     // an option!
            textColor: 'yellow' // an option!
        }
        // any other event sources...
    ]
});
```

Comment: My problem here is that i don't have acces to the backend implementation, so im looking for a front-end only implementation... that's why i need to select the DOM elements... thanks anyways! any ideas?

Comment: So for example in the event above that spans 3 weeks, you want that same event to have different colors for each of the 3 weeks? Or do you just want one color for each event? Do you want a color for a specific event type or just random?

If you don't have any back-end access you can parse the events feed and manually add the color?

Comment: I want every instance of the same event to have a random color (yes, the 3 weeks that the event lasts).

Answer (score 23):

You could try using the eventAfterRender callback. Check [documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterRender/).

This way, you will get the 'whole' event, and manipulate its color, based on a random choice.

Just so you could get an idea, i work with this callback, but the color is changed based on the day of the event. The color changes if the event is scheduled, is happening, or had already happened.

```
eventAfterRender: function (event, element, view) {
        var dataHoje = new Date();
        if (event.start < dataHoje && event.end > dataHoje) {
            //event.color = "#FFB347"; //Em andamento
            element.css('background-color', '#FFB347');
        } else if (event.start < dataHoje && event.end < dataHoje) {
            //event.color = "#77DD77"; //Concluído OK
            element.css('background-color', '#77DD77');
        } else if (event.start > dataHoje && event.end > dataHoje) {
            //event.color = "#AEC6CF"; //Não iniciado
            element.css('background-color', '#AEC6CF');
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks! interesting but when I apply a (cached) random color ( element.css('color',mycachedrandomcolor); ) every line (even from same event) gets a different color; any idea why?

Comment: Thats weird... maybe try the eventRender callback [link](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/)

Answer (score 4):

Events list object in which you have properties like start, end, overlap,, rendering you also have a property called color in which you can specify color of the event.

Look at below demo code in which color property is used:

```
        events: [
            {
                start: '2017-11-24',
                end: '2017-11-28',
                overlap: false,
                rendering: 'background',
                color: '#257e4a'
            },
            {
                start: '2017-11-06',
                end: '2017-11-08',
                overlap: false,
                rendering: 'background',
                color: '#ff9f89'
            }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this. eventsArr [{id...other..color..},{},]

```
           var SelectedData = eventsArr.filter(function (arr) {
                return arr.id === id;
            })[0];
```

after set a color then update color to event associated with that ID. In your case, just for each loop through those id assign differ colors.

```
var color = SelectedData.color;
$("#YourElementID").find("#ElementIDtoBeChanged").val(color);
```