# Changing Event Color in fullcalendar using dynamic data with a category tag

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am currrently using jQuery `Fullcalendar` to display events that are selected by catergories and tags. I would like to change event color based on the categories of the event, e.g. adult will be one color, and airport will be another color, etc....

I really don't know where to start. I have tried using

```
eventAfterRender function (event, element, view){
    var categoryName = new categoryName();
    if (event.categoryName < ) {
       element.css('background-color', '#FFB347');
    } else if 
     etc......
```

Here is an example of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        weekends: false,
        header: {
            left: "prev,next",
            center: "title",
            right: "today"
        },

        eventRender: function (event, data, element) {
            element.qtip({
                content: '<h3>'+ event.title +'</h3>' + 
                '<p><b>Start:</b> '+ data.start +'<br />' + 
                (data.end && '<p><b>End:</b> ' + data.end + '</p>' || ''),               
            });
        },

        editable: false,
        eventLimit: 3,
        events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/colapi/COLCalendarEvents/Mauro',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    tagValue: $('#Tags').val(),
                    categoryValue: $('#Cat').val(),
                    start: start.format("l"),
                    end: end.format("l"),
                    categoryName: "category",
                    tagName: "tags",
                },
                success: function (doc) {
                    callback(doc);
                }               
            });

        },        
        eventClick: function openPopup(event) {
            var oManager = GetRadWindowManager();
            var oRW = oManager.open($('#ModalPopupURL').val() + event.url, null);
            return false;
        },        

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eventRender` for setting custom style based on your code.
I did it for some custom color setting based on condition.

Below is an example of that.

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
            element.attr('title', event.eventTitle);
            element.find('.fc-title').html(event.eventTitle);
            var isAcceptByApplicant = event.data.isAcceptByApplicant;
            if (isAcceptByApplicant == null) {
                $(element).addClass("new_interview");
                $(element).find(".fc-content").attr("style", "border-left:3px solid #004085 !important"); 
            }
            else if (isAcceptByApplicant == false) {
                $(element).addClass("cancel_interview");
                $(element).find(".fc-content").attr("style", "border-left:3px solid #721c24 !important");
            }
            else {
                $(element).addClass("accept_interview");
                $(element).find(".fc-content").attr("style", "border-left:3px solid #219653 !important");
            }
        }
```

here with `event` I supplied my required data and check the condition to set the dynamic style.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at FullCalendar's [Coloring Events](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Colors/). Full Calendar provides `eventBackgroundColor`, `eventBorderColor` and `eventTextColor` which you can use to distinguish different category of events.

You can add these properties in events JSON and fullCalendar will take care of that. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619903/jquery-full-calendar-set-a-different-color-to-each-event-from-front-end) as well.

Comment: **NOTE** The latest version **fullcalendar v5.5** doesn't provide `eventAfterRender`. You should use `eventDidMount` if you want to dynamically change the colors using style. Or you can add `eventColor` and more colors for your events.