# Full Calendar: Coloring events using IF statement

Tags: javascript, php, html, fullcalendar

I have a calendar based upon tickets opened by the site administrator. We have four type of tickets:

1. Pending
2. In process
3. Finished
4. Cancelled

This is the `div` in which I have the calendar:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-10 col-sm-11">
   <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" data-background-color="blue">
         <h4 class="title">Calendario</h4>
      </div>
      <br>
      <section class="content">
         <?php
            $events = TicketData::getEvents();
                foreach($events as $event){
                    $thejson[] = array("title"=>$event->title,"url"=>"./?view=editticket&id=".$event->id,"start"=>$event->date_at."T".$event->time_at);
                }
            // print_r(json_encode($thejson));
            ?>
         <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next, today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
                    defaultDate: jQuery.now(),
                    editable: false,
                    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                    events: <?php echo json_encode($thejson); ?>
                });

            });
         </script>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <div id="calendar">
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
   </div>
</div>
```

The database structure for the tickets is simple: `id`, `title`, `description`, `date_at`, `time_at`, `created_at`, `tecnico_id` and `status_id`.

I would like to "colorize" the events using an if script:

This is the code I have, however it doesn't work.

```
<section class="content">
         <?php
            $events = TicketData::getEvents();
              // $status->status_id;
                foreach($events as $event){
                    $thejson[] = array("title"=>$event->title,"url"=>"./?view=editticket&id=".$event->id,"start"=>$event->date_at."T".$event->time_at,);
                $thejsonColor[] = array($event->status_id);
                }
            // print_r(json_encode($thejson));
            ?>
         <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next, today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
                    defaultDate: jQuery.now(),
                    editable: false,
                    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                    events: <?php echo json_encode($thejson); ?>,
                if ($thejsonColor=1){
                  eventColor: 'fb8c00'
                }else if ($thejsonColor=2){
                  eventColor: 'ff0'
                } else if ($thejsonColor=3){
                  eventColor: '43a047'
                } else {
                  eventColor: '00acc1'
                }
                });             
            });
         </script>
```

[This is the calendar generated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UE8hh.png)
[These are the colors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmZFz.png)

I want to make them match the color criteria, so the user has an idea of which tickets are the ones that are pending, incomplete, complete and cancelled.
I'm a newbie to javascript and I don't know how to make this. Can you guys help me or point me on how I should do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery full calendar: set a different color to each event from front-end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619903/jquery-full-calendar-set-a-different-color-to-each-event-from-front-end)

Comment: @PradeepPatel no, Toni Michel Caubet didn't had access to the backend code, and she _wants every instance of the same event to have a random color_.

Comment: I want to have a specific color when `status_id` matches the criteria left in the commented pseudocode.

Comment: since you're generating your JSON using PHP, use the PHP script to set the colour property. If you are unable to change the PHP for any reason, use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDataTransform which will run once for every event, then you can set the colour property according to your rules and return the updated event object, which will then be rendered onto the calendar.

Comment: @ADyson that's what I want to do (set the colour property using php), but I just don't know _how to do it_ lol. Check my update, that's what I had in mind but it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the color as you iterate through the array of events:

```
<?php
    // helper function to pick the right color
    function getColor($id) {
        $eventColor = '';
        if ($id == 1) {
            $eventColor = '#fb8c00';
        } else if ($id == 2) {
            $eventColor = '#ff0';
        } else if ($id == 3) {
            $eventColor = '#43a047';
        } else {
            $eventColor = '#00acc1';
        }
        return $eventColor;
    }

    $events = TicketData::getEvents(); //pulls the events from TicketData.php
    foreach($events as $event) {
        $thejson[] = array(
            "title" => $event->title,
            "url" => "./?view=editticket&id=".$event->id,
            "start" => $event->date_at."T".$event->time_at,
            "color" => getColor($event->status_id));
    }

?>
```

Then just echo the events like you are doing now:

```
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next, today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                defaultDate: jQuery.now(),
                editable: false,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                events: <?php echo json_encode($thejson); ?>,
            });             
        });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it by select from your table in php like:

```
$sql = "SELECT CASE WHEN tickets='Pending'" THEN '#C6E0B4' WHEN tickets='In progres' THEN '#FFFF99' END AS color" 
$schedules = $conn->query($sql); 
$sched_res = []; 
foreach($schedules->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $row){  
    $sched_res[$row['id']] = $row;
}
```

Then just echo the events like you are doing now:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next, today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: jQuery.now(),
            editable: false,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: <?php echo json_encode($thejson); ?>,
        });             
    });
 </script>
```